# AWS lambda returning Internal server error for simple return json code based on python for no reason

Tags: python, json, lambda, aws-lambda

In Lambda function, I am returning output as below

```
output = {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "headers": {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            "body": json.dumps({'success': true})
        }
        #json.dumps('Email sent! Message ID:' + response['MessageId'])
        return output
```

and it returns following error message:

```
{
    "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

However if I change following line

```
json.dumps({'success': true})
```

to

```
json.dumps('Email sent! Message ID:' + response['MessageId'])
```

It works fine. I want to return a json back, what needs to be done?

Answer (score 1):

I think python's Json Boolean value has to be either True or False (First letter capital).
Try `json.dumps({'success': True})`